# AppLocalizations without calling `of(context)` every time

Tags: flutter, dart

I find the localization procedure using [the official Flutter localization plugin](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) cumbersome. To display a localized string I have to call `AppLocalizations.of(context).myAppTitle` - not exactly sleek or easy to glance over in a huge nested Widget tree with lots of localized strings. Not to mention it looks ugly.

Is there a way to make the usage nicer? For example, can I use a global variable or a static class with a `AppLocalizations` instance member to make the access easier? For example declaring a top level `AppLocalizations` variable

```
// Somewhere in the global scope
AppLocalizations l;


// main.dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getLocaleSomehow().then((locale){ 
            l = Localization(locale);
            setState((){}); 
        });
    }
}
```

Then I could simply call

```
Text(l.myAppTitle)
```

So in an essence what I'm asking is "what are the dangers and/or disadvantages of not calling `AppLocalizations.of(context)`?"

If I really do need to use the `.of(BuildContext)` method to access the `AppLocalizations` instance - can I at least store it in my `StatefulWidget`? I'm thinking something like

```
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget{
    AppLocalizations _l;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _l = AppLocalizations.of(context);

        // ... build widgets ...
    }
}
```

Or is there any other way to make the localization less cumbersome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is totally fine to store the `Localization` object inside of your `State` and it works very well in that case.

If you want to only make it look nicer, you could also just declare the variable in the build method:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final l = Localization.of(context);

  return Text(l.myAppTitle);
}
```

In a `StatefulWidget`, you could also re-assign the variable in [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) or just assign it once using the null-aware `??=` operator because the object will not change over time:

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Localization l;

  @override
  didChangeDependencies() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    l ??= Localization.of(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale> locale) {
    l = Localization.of(context);
    super.didChangeLocales(locale);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(l.myAppTite);
}
```

In `didChangeLocales`, you can re-assign every time. This makes sure that the variable always holds the appropriate locale and is initialized at first build (with `didChangeDependencies`). Notice that I also included a `WidgetsBindingObserver`, which you need to handle as shown in the code.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that there is a `didChangeLocales()` method as well - would it be better to use that than `didChangeDependencies()`?

Comment: @MagnusW You could use a combination of both. I added what I mean to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I combined some of the info from the other responses here (specialy Fleximex's) to a solution which I found quite interesting - and that's the one I'm using. I created an extension on the `BuildContext` itself.

```
extension BuildContextHelper on BuildContext {
  AppLocalizations get l {
    // if no locale was found, returns a default
    return AppLocalizations.of(this) ?? AppLocalizationsEn();
  }
}
```

Using this extension (and importing it), one can use it like this:

```
context.l.appTitle
```

or

```
context.l.helloUser(name)
```

IMHO it's clean and readable, it's not the shortest though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is needed.
You *could* work around it, but that is a bad idea.

The reason for this is that `Localization.of<T>(context, T)` may update over time. A few situations where it does are:

- The locale changed
- The LocalizationsDelegate obtained was asynchronously loaded
- MaterialApp/CupertinoApp got updated with new translations

If you're not properly calling `Localization.of` inside *build* as you should, then in those scenarios your UI may fail to properly update.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was suspecting. But let's say I don't care about changing the language of my app (without the need of a restart) when the user changes the device locale, is there still any danger of keeping a global reference to the `Localization` instance? After all, I'd bet that most users don't change their locale after setting up a device for the first time...

Comment: Yes. Like I said, that can also be needed when the translations are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: I'm trying to do localizations, but there are problems when I want to get the strings oninitState which is before the context is made .  I also have several service objects which work on user selected translated menu button strings. or return strings that need to be translated.  I'm thinking of switching to easy localization

Comment: Unfortunately, you forget that there is a need for localization even outside the usual UI. Background services, various event handlers, notfications, situations without a direct UI.

Answer (score 3):

By using Flutter extensions you can now simply extend The `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`, or the generic `Widget` to provide a translate method. Two different solutions:

**1. on `Widget`**

```
extension TranslationHelper on Widget {
  String tr(BuildContext context, String key) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(key);
  }
}
```

Then in the `build` method of a `StatelessWidget` you can call `tr(context, 'title')`. For the `build` method of a `StatefulWidget` you have to call `widget.tr(context, 'title')`.

**2. on `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`**

For a more consistent calling of the translate function you can extend `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`, respectively:

```
extension TranslationHelperStateless on StatelessWidget {
  String tr(BuildContext context, String key) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(key);
  }
}
```

```
extension TranslationHelperStateful<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  String tr(BuildContext context, String key) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(key);
  }
}
```

For both `build` methods in `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` you can call:

```
tr(context, 'title')
```

With `StatefulWidget` there is one risk as a developer you need to avoid. Which is calling the `tr()` method in a place where you can access `context` but where the `build` method has not ran yet, like `initState`. Make sure to call `tr()` always in the `build` methods.

**3. on `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`, but not using the `translate` method**

You can extend `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` and return the `AppLocalizations`, like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

extension TranslationHelperStateless on StatelessWidget {
  AppLocalizations tr(BuildContext context) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
  }
}

extension TranslationHelperStateful<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  AppLocalizations tr(BuildContext context) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
  }
}
```

For both `build` methods in `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` you can call:

```
tr(context).title
```

or

```
tr(context).helloUser(name)
```

Comment: I like these suggestions, but the first several utilize a `translate` method that does not exist in the `intl` API as far as I can find. Is this meant to be a placeholder for a custom function that can handle dynamic keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own text widget and do localization there.You can replace all your text widgets with your own MyText widget.

```
class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  String data;
  InlineSpan textSpan;
  TextStyle style;
  StrutStyle strutStyle;
  TextAlign textAlign;
  TextDirection textDirection;
  Locale locale;
  bool softWrap;
  TextOverflow overflow;
  double textScaleFactor;
  int maxLines;
  String semanticsLabel;
  TextWidthBasis textWidthBasis;

  MyText(
    this.data, {
    Key key,
    this.style,
    this.strutStyle,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.locale,
    this.softWrap,
    this.overflow,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.maxLines,
    this.semanticsLabel,
    this.textWidthBasis,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      Localization.of(context).data,
      style: style,
      semanticsLabel: semanticsLabel,
      locale: locale,
      key: key,
      textAlign: textAlign,
      maxLines: maxLines,
      overflow: overflow,
      softWrap: softWrap,
      strutStyle: strutStyle,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
      textWidthBasis: textWidthBasis,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**12/06/2023**

Remember that the AppLocalizations is an abstract class. The classes implementing that abstract class are each of your laguages defined on the .arb files. For example I have an app_en.arb (for english) and an app_es.arb (for spanish), thus, the implementing classes are AppLocalizationsEn and AppLocalizationsEs.

In my case I save the Locale language code on the shared preferences (if there's no value saved yet I take the english language code as default):

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart';

void function(){
AppLocalizations appLocalizations;
String? localeLanguageCode =
  businessPreferences.getString("languageKey");
  switch (localeLanguageCode) {
    case "en":
    appLocalizations = AppLocalizationsEn();
    break;
    case "es":
    appLocalizations = AppLocalizationsEs();
    break;
    default:
    appLocalizations = AppLocalizationsEn();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try create extensions for context:

```
extension BuildContextExt on BuildContext {
  AppLocalizations get l10n => AppLocalizations.of(this)!;
}
```

And then use:

```
context.l10n
```