# Flutter localization without context

Tags: flutter, localization

I am trying to localize my app in flutter. I created the needed string.arb files for the supported languages.

Why does `AppLocalizations.of(context)` need a context?

I simply want to access the named strings in the files/locales files/classes.
At some point in the app I  build a List and fill it later via overriding some fields with a separate class.

However, this class has no context but I want to use localized strings in it.
Can I write a method which gets me the Localization of whatever String I put in?

Comment: In another StackOverflow thread I'm proposing a solution using Flutter Extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68754936/7052599

Comment: This is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69037938/1034225

Answer (score 14):

We can resolve this by using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) easily, we can use the string anywhere after this setup.

1. Install this to your vscode [Flutter Intl VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl)
2. setup `pubspec.yaml`

   ```
   dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   flutter_localizations:                          # Add this line
     sdk: flutter                                  # Add this line
   intl: ^0.17.0                                   # Add this line
   get_it: ^7.2.0                                  # Add this line


   flutter:
     uses-material-design: true
     generate: true                                # Add this line


   flutter_intl:                                   # Add this line
     enabled: true                                 # Add this line
     class_name: I10n                              # Add this line
     main_locale: en                               # Add this line
     arb_dir: lib/core/localization/l10n           # Add this line
     output_dir: lib/core/localization/generated   # Add this line
   ```
3. Setup `main.dart`

   ```
   import 'package:component_gallery/core/localization/generated/l10n.dart';
   import 'package:component_gallery/locator.dart';
   import 'package:component_gallery/ui/pages/home.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

   void main() {
     setupLocator();
     runApp(App());
   }

   class App extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         localizationsDelegates: [
           I10n.delegate,
           GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
           GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
           GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
         ],
         supportedLocales: I10n.delegate.supportedLocales,
         localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
           if (supportedLocales
               .map((e) => e.languageCode)
               .contains(deviceLocale?.languageCode)) {
             return deviceLocale;
           } else {
             return const Locale('en', '');
           }
         },
         home: HomePage(),
       );
     }
   }
   ```
4. setup `locator.dart`

   ```
   import 'package:component_gallery/core/services/navigation_service.dart';
   import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

   GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

   void setupLocator() {
     locator.registerLazySingleton(() => I10n());
   }
   ```
5. Use it with Get_it without context as

   ```
   final I10n _i10n = locator<I10n>();
   class MessageComponent extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Text(
         _i10n.sample,
         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: According from get_it https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#why-getit ,  is Extremely fast (O(1)) when testing

Comment: Do you have any example project using this method?

Comment: If you are already using bloc, it is not recommended to use get_it with it.

Comment: @Ataberk Why is it not recommended? Do you know where I can find info about why?

Comment: What is the `component_gallery` package? From which package you get the `I10n` object and what it's purpose?

Comment: @Ataberk Please recommend another package or another way to implement dependency injection? or should I Use another state management Like riverpod?

Comment: @FadyFouad, what Ataberk is saying does not make any sense. Your state management choice doesn't have anything to do with your DI choice. You can perfectly use GetIt with bloc.

Comment: @genericUser component_gallery is the name of the project of the example

Answer (score 13):

If you would prefer to not use a package then here is a solution that worked for me. Now the most [common implementation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) of `AppLocalizations` I've seen usually has these two lines:

```dart
//.........
static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
  return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
}
//.........
```

The implementation of the delegate would look something like this:

```dart
class _AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();

    return localizations;
  }

  //... the rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice the load method on the delegate returns a `Future<AppLocalizations>`. The load method is usually called once from main and never again so you can take advantage of that by adding a static instance of `AppLocalizations` to the delegate. So now your delegate would look like this:

```dart
class _AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  static AppLocalizations instance;

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();

    instance = localizations; // set the static instance here

    return localizations;
  }

  //... the rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Then on your `AppLocalizations` class you would now have:

```dart
//.........
static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
  return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
}

static AppLocalizations get instance => _AppLocalizationsDelegate.instance; // add this
//.........
```

Now in your translate helper method you could have:

```dart
String tr(String key) {
    return AppLocalizations.instance.translate(key);
}
```

No context needed.

Comment: how is that supposed to work, when the app_localizations.dart is autogenerated and overwritten in its entirety, any time arb files are changed?

Comment: Really wish you'd have put a full example up. This is impossible for a new dart developer to follow.

Comment: cool approach, thanks!

Comment: In this way `instance` will be null when called from background service (when app closed)

Comment: As @CeeMcSharpface says, I think it is not a solution to modify generated files

Answer (score 11):

If you know the desired `Locale` then you could use:

```
final locale = Locale('en');
AppLocalizations t = await AppLocalizations.delegate.load(locale);
println(t.someTranslationKey);
```

Instead of hardcoding `Locale('en')` you could implement some kind of resolver to find out what the desired locale is. The supported languages are `AppLocalizations.supportedLocales`.

Comment: If you're somewhere with an UI displayed (as opposed to eg. a background service) then you can get the current locale from the system, making it this one-liner: `final t = await AppLocalizations.delegate.load(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locale)`. But this will return the `und` undefined locale if there's no UI present.

Comment: Considering that we use the `intl` package, anyway, the following works in some cases even without an UI: `final t = await AppLocalizations.delegate.load(Locale(Intl.getCurrentLocale()));` but without fallback. So, for instance, on an `en_US` device it won't automatically find the `en` localization.

Comment: @Gábor What's the use-case for changing language in background?

Comment: I didn't intend to _change_ it, just to _use_ it. But as I wrote in an answer below, I now use Flutter Intl which I found to be superior to the "standard" gen_l10n solution, in three important areas. This was one of them: Flutter Intl provides non-context localization out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 8):

There is a library called [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) that does localization without context, you can simply use that one. Library also provides more convenient approach of writing less code and still localizing all the segments of the app. An example main class:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]).then((_) {
    runApp(EasyLocalization(
      child: MyApp(),
      useOnlyLangCode: true,
      startLocale: Locale('nl'),
      fallbackLocale: Locale('nl'),
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('nl'),
        Locale('en'),
      ],
      path: 'lang',
    ));
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
      supportedLocales: EasyLocalization.of(context).supportedLocales,
      locale: EasyLocalization.of(context).locale,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        EasyLocalization.of(context).delegate,
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
        if (locale == null) {
          EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = supportedLocales.first;
          Intl.defaultLocale = '${supportedLocales.first}';
          return supportedLocales.first;
        }

        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode) {
            EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = supportedLocale;
            Intl.defaultLocale = '$supportedLocale';
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }

        EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = supportedLocales.first;
        Intl.defaultLocale = '${supportedLocales.first}';
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Also don't forget to put localization path to your `pubspec.yamal` file!

After all of this is done, you can simply just use it in a `Text` widget like this:

```
Text(tr('someJsonKey'),),
```

Comment: It seems there is no documentation. I am unsure how to use this exactly.

Comment: What do you mean there is no documentation? You need to open the link (open readme page of the plugin), there is a tutorial on how to integrate it and use it throughout the app. Main part is integrating it in main function, and than using it just by calling tr("keyFromJSONFile")

Comment: When I integrate it into the App, I get an error message on launch saying that the localization file could not be found. Changing it does not help at all

Comment: That is due to some error in main.dart file, and some piece of the puzzle not integrated by the docs of the plugin. I will update my answer with main file example so please check what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The package you suggested is awesome!

Comment: It is still tied to the context.

Comment: It needs context: https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/210

Answer (score 7):

**Latest:** the current [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) plugin makes this approach obsolete, at least if you use a supported IDE. You have a context-free alternative there:

```
S.current.translationKey
```

---

**Previous:** Starting from the suggestions of [Stuck,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545232/2076286) this is the final solution I found. It isn't as cheap as the simple lookup with the context, so only use it if really necessary and make sure you call it once and use as many times as possible. But this approach works even if you have no context at all, for instance, you are in a background service or any other program part without UI.

```dart
Future<AppLocalizations> loadLocalization() async {
  final parts = Intl.getCurrentLocale().split('_');
  final locale = Locale(parts.first, parts.last);
  return await AppLocalizations.delegate.load(locale);
}
```

Using it is just the same as usual:

```dart
final t = await loadLocalization();
print(t.translationKey);
```

Update: the singleton I suggested in the comments could look like:

```dart
class Localization {
  static final Localization _instance = Localization._internal();
  AppLocalizations? _current;

  Localization._internal();

  factory Localization() => _instance;

  Future<AppLocalizations> loadCurrent() async {
    if (_current == null) {
      final parts = Intl.getCurrentLocale().split('_');
      final locale = Locale(parts.first, parts.last);
      _current = await AppLocalizations.delegate.load(locale);
    }
    return Future.value(_current);
  }

  void invalidate() {
    _current = null;
  }
}
```

and used like:

```
final t = await Localization().loadCurrent();
```

To keep track of language changes, call this from your main `build()`:

```
PlatformDispatcher.instance.onLocaleChanged = () => Localization().invalidate();
```

Comment: This approach will not work if we have a class containing translated strings. If the user changes the app language on the fly, the translated strings from the class will not update to the new language.

Comment: In my own experience, this is the _only_ solution that works. Yes, it's your responsibility to invalidate your cached version when needed (you may want to rely on `didChangeLocales()` or `PlatformDispatcher.onLocaleChanged` or a `Provider` of your own. But at least you can get localization. All the other alternatives I tried (eg. building `MaterialApp` with a `navigatorKey` and using that to obtain a context) failed miserably.

Comment: Provider is not an option as it requires context, if we had context then we would call AppLocalizations in the standard manor. I am going to check didChangeLocales(), to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Not directly, no. But you can keep this whole lot in a singleton and use the `Provider` or any other means to invalidate from the UI-based code when necessary. The non-UI parts of your app can use that singleton to do the string lookup when needed.

Answer (score 6):

My 2 cents into it, just not to loose the solution :)

I totally get why Flutter localization solutions needs BuildContext - makes total sense. But, if I explicitly don't want runtime language switch, and happy with the app restart?

That's the solution I came up with that seems to work pretty well.

Assuming you've followed Flutter's [official localization steps](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), create a global variable that will be used to accessing the `AppLocalizations` class.

i18n.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

AppLocalizations get tr => _tr!; // helper function to avoid typing '!' all the time
AppLocalizations? _tr; // global variable 

class AppTranslations {
  static init(BuildContext context) {
    _tr = AppLocalizations.of(context);
  }
}
```

Now, somewhere in your main wrapper (the one below `MaterialApp`) call to set the localizations for the currently selected locale:

```dart
    AppTranslations.init(context);
```

It could be `initState()` or even `build()` of the main widget (it's safe to call this multiple times, obviously).

Now you can simply call:

```dart
import 'package:my_app/i18n.dart'

...
  Text(tr.welcome_text)

  // or

  print(tr.welcome_text);
...
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working as expected,  am getting the error: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) on the line AppLocalizations get tr => _tr!;

Answer (score 5):

I was already using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package, so this found me very easy.

Trick I used to get app language without context as below

*en-US.json*

```
{
   "app_locale":"en"
}
```

*ar-SA.json*

```
{
   "app_locale":"ar"
}
```

Used it like a way in utility/extension function

```
LocaleKeys.app_locale.tr() //will return 'en' for English, 'ar' for Arabic
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is using Flutter Intl (Flutter i18n plugins) as it is built by Flutter developers. It has a method to use without context like the following (Code example from the [Visual Studio Marketplace details page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl)):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
        Text(
            S.of(context).pageHomeConfirm,
        ),
        Text(
            S.current.pageHomeConfirm,// If you don't have `context` to pass
        ),
    ]);
}
```

More details on [official plugin page](https://localizely.com/blog/flutter-i18n-plugin/) and [Visual Studio Marketplace details page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using the Minimal internationalization version.

Adapting chinloyal's answer to the [Minimal internationalization version](https://github.com/flutter/website/tree/master/examples/internationalization/minimal).

Apply chinloyal's solution but with this difference:

From this:

```
  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture<AppLocalizations>(AppLocalizations(locale));
  }
```

To this:

```
  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    var localizations =
        await SynchronousFuture<AppLocalizations>(AppLocalizations(locale));

    instance = localizations; // set the static instance here

    return localizations;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a mobile app, this one liner did it for me:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

AppLocalizations get l10n {
  return lookupAppLocalizations(ui.PlatformDispatcher.instance.locale);
}
```

If you're building an app with multiple windows, it looks like the easiest way to do this synchronously is to set the global translation when the app starts and update the language code manually using docs described [on the intl package](https://github.com/dart-lang/i18n/tree/main/pkgs/intl).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code:

```
final appLocalizations = await AppLocalizations.delegate
      .load(Locale(Platform.localeName.substring(0, 2)));
print(appLocalizations.yourCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a singleton class like this:

```
class LocalizationManager {
  static final LocalizationManager instance = LocalizationManager._();
  LocalizationManager._();

  late AppLocalizations _localization;

  AppLocalizations get appLocalization => _localization;

  void setLocalization(BuildContext context) {
    _localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
  }
}
```

then in the material app builder, set the value of localization:

```
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    LocalizationManager.instance.setLocalization(context);
    return child!;
  },
)
```