# How to access flutter localization without a context

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I am using flutter localization from their official documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), and I am using clean architecture in my project. I want to access the app localization class without a context so I can translate the error messages in the repository file.

Here is an example:

```
class UserRepository{
  Future<Either<Failure, Unit>> logOut() async{
    try{
      return const Right(unit);
    }catch(e){
      return const Left(AuthFailure('I want to translate this error based on app`s language'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter localization without context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563074/flutter-localization-without-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since this is not the best practice to do, you can create a custom localizations widget that gets you the `Localizations.of(context)` but here the `context` will be obtained by a `GlobalKey` that you to get from a widget that we can access the `Localization` widget context with it, which is inside the `MaterialApp` of course.

For this, you can use the `navigatorKey` to achieve it:

```
// somewhere else in your project
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> ourNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

// main.dart
MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: ourNavigatorKey,
//...
```

Now that you assigned that key, you can create a `WithoutContextLocalizations` widget:

```
Localizations withoutContextLocalizations() {
  final BuildContext context = ourNavigatorKey.currentContext!;
  return Localizations.of<Localizations>(context, Localizations)!;
}
```

Now from any place instead of using :

```
Localizations.of(context);
```

You can use :

```
WithoutContextLocalizations();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution since it is not best practice to use context inside data classes.

you can create a singleton class like this:

```
class LocalizationManager {
  static final LocalizationManager instance = LocalizationManager._();
  LocalizationManager._();

  late AppLocalizations _localization;

  AppLocalizations get appLocalization => _localization;

  void setLocalization(BuildContext context) {
    _localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
  }
}
```

then in the material app builder, set the value of localization:

```
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    LocalizationManager.instance.setLocalization(context);
    return child!;
  },
)
```