# Different methods of internationalizing/localizing Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

According to [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), we can add localized messages by 2 methods:

#### Method 1

1. Add the following into the `pubspec.yaml` file.

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     flutter_localizations:
       sdk: flutter
     intl: ^0.17.0
   flutter:
    generate: true
   ```
2. Create a `<project-root>/l10n.yaml` file containing:

   ```yaml
   arb-dir: lib/l10n
   template-arb-file: app_en.arb
   output-localization-file: demo_localizations.dart
   ```
3. In `<project-root/l10n.yaml>`, create `app_locale.arb` for your translation files. For example:

   - `app_en.arb`

   ```
   {
     "@@locale": "en",
     "helloWorld": "Hello World!"
   }
   ```

   - `app_es.arb`

   ```
   {
     "@@locale": "es",
     "helloWorld": "Hola Mundo!"
   }
   ```
4. `demo_localizations.dart` will be generated and can be imported to `main.dart` like this:

   ```dart
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/demo_localizations.dart';

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         localizationsDelegates: DemoLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
         supportedLocales: DemoLocalizations.supportedLocales,
         title: 'My app',
         home: ... ,
       );
     }
   }
   ```

#### Method 2: Defining a class for the app’s localized resources

1. Add the following into the `pubspec.yaml` file.

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     flutter_localizations:
       sdk: flutter
     intl: ^0.17.0
     intl_translation:
   flutter:
    generate: true
   ```
2. Create a `DemoLocalizations` class that uses `initializeMessages()` and `Intl.message()`.

   ```dart
   class DemoLocalizations {
     DemoLocalizations(this.localeName);

     static Future<DemoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
       final String name = locale.countryCode == null || locale.countryCode!.isEmpty
           ? locale.languageCode
           : locale.toString();
       final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(name);

       return initializeMessages(localeName).then((_) {
         return DemoLocalizations(localeName);
       });
     }

     static DemoLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
       return Localizations.of<DemoLocalizations>(context, DemoLocalizations)!;
     }

     final String localeName;

     String get title {
       return Intl.message(
         'Hello World',
         name: 'title',
         desc: 'Title for the Demo application',
         locale: localeName,
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create a `DemoLocalizationsDelegate` class.

   ```dart
   class DemoLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalizations> {
     const DemoLocalizationsDelegate();

     @override
     bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'es'].contains(locale.languageCode);

     @override
     Future<DemoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) => DemoLocalizations.load(locale);

     @override
     bool shouldReload(DemoLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
   }
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   flutter pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n lib/demo_localizations.dart
   ```

   to generate `intl_messages.arb` file. Add `intl_en.arb` and `intl_es.arb` as your translation files.
5. With the app’s root directory as the current directory, run

   ```
   flutter pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-use-deferred-loading lib/demo_localizations.dart lib/l10n/intl_*.arb
   ```

   to generate `intl_messages_<locale>.dart` for each `intl_<locale>.arb` file and `intl_messages_all.dart`, which imports all of the messages files.
6. Import the required classes into `main.dart`.

   ```dart
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'demo_localizations.dart';
   import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
   import 'l10n/messages_all.dart';

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         localizationsDelegates: DemoLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
         supportedLocales: DemoLocalizations.supportedLocales,
         title: 'My app',
         home: ... ,
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Are there any differences between these 2 methods? Can I know why we use Method 2 since there are more steps involved?

Comment: Check this blog https://roszkowski.dev/2021/i18n-in-flutter/. Its now easier because the package handles all creating/building/setting the files

Comment: @Reign Does that mean that Method 2 was just an older approach before Method 1 was introduced?

Comment: The easiest solution can be using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get#internationalization) package

Comment: @Ranjit I would like to use a native solution instead of depending on another package. Also, I am asking about the **rationale** behind the decision instead of **how** to internationalize the app. You did not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that what you describe as "Method #1" is the latest version of how to do it in Flutter with no external means. It's now simpler than ever to do it without external packages.

The other methods are from the "before times" where you had to do more work to get it up and running, which is why there are so many alternative packages, some of which seem obsolete now, that the Flutter system itself has changed and become simpler and more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The downside of the intl packages, it requires to use call the class within the context.
for the example

```
S.of(context).nameOfLocalizedText
```

I think it's worth trying a different approach to create a class with static strings and localization switcher refers to the current locale. And just call the class only without the context. Unfortunately, I don't have the example but you can try to create a class for the language switcher, a class mapper for map the JSON into a class, and a map<string, string> for containing the language dictionary. Hope it'll help you out.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676774/10661805).

Comment: Well, Rémi Rousselet say that. but little disagree, that's is a different scenario. What he meant is using intl and calling it without context. But he doesn't say that we can do it custom way right? intl localization it's not real-time when you change the language you must navigate to the root route, meanwhile, we are required to use the provider at the materialapp / cuppertino app to listen what is the current localization to change it in real-time.

Comment: But it's come back to you, perhaps intl & intl_translation package is the best advice to do it "safe way". I think it's worth trying since flutter doesn't have a strings system like an android native does, instead of using the .arb file and S.of(context).